# add a git repository to remine, but it have no history

Tags: git, history, redmine

The project's repository is effective and I can see the files.
The problem is I can't get the history. 
Here is the snapshot:
[image]

[image]

How could I do? I can paste some configuration if you need.

Comment: There is no where near enough information in your questions for us to help. Some things you could check are: redmine server logs, does your git repo have any actual history to show?

Comment: Thanks for you. The redmine environment is complicated and I have given up.